# Why does Sora no otoshimono have different ending themes per episode?

Tags: sora-no-otoshimono

I've finished watching the Anime's First Season and I noticed that every episode in the anime has different ending themes.

As you can see in this [list of episodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Heaven%27s_Lost_Property_episodes). Heaven's lost property has different ending sequences and different ending themes for a 12-episode series anime. Is there a significant reason for this?

Comment: There is not a particular reason for this. There have been several animes which did that. (ie: In lucky star, the endings are completely different each episode, in the monogatari series and Yosuga no Sora the EDs are different per mini arc(3-4eps), in Rokka no Yuusha the Eds have the same song but the video changes based on each character,etc) .

Answer (score -1):

It has different endings because they are after scenes for each respective episode and shows what is happening after each episodes misadventure.

Comment: But you can still play the same ending theme before you show the post credit scenes, no? How does this answer the question?

Comment: I don't think most people stay after repetitive ending credits so they yo

Comment: So they use different endings continuing from the episode. Maybe it was just the studios preferences